# Java code for finding the next palindrome - Error in output

Tags: java, palindrome

The problem is to find the smallest palindrome integer after the given number.

1. Input the number of integers i.e test cases.
2. Input the integers in an array.
3. Output: The next palindrome integer corresponding to each integer in the array respectively.

There are various methods to solve this problem(many solutions on SO as well), but I cannot figure out why I can't get the output from this code. From running the code many times, I have concluded that if any test case needs more than 1 increment to become a palindrome, the program goes into an infinite loop somehow. 
Eg. If I input 100 as a test case, the output is 101.Similarly, if I enter 908, I get 909 as output. But if I enter 108, I do not get 111 as the output.

Please bear with my silly mistakes, I'm new to coding in Java. Thanks

```
import java.util.Scanner;


class nextPalindrome {

    public static void nextPalindromeGenerate(int n)
    {   
        int flag=1;         
        int digit;          //to store the mod value
        int rev=0;          //reverse of the number
        int original;       //dummy to store the original number

        if(n<10)
        {   System.out.println(n+1);    //If number is single digit, next smallest palindrome is n+1
            flag=0;


        }


        while(flag!=0)
        {   ++n;
            original=n;

            while(n>0)      //loop for reversing the number
            {
                digit=n%10;
                rev=rev*10+digit;
                n=n/10;
            }

            if(rev==original)   //check if original equals the reverse(original)
            {
                System.out.println(rev);
                flag=0;


            }

            else flag=1;
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {   

    @SuppressWarnings("resource")
    Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);




        int n=sc.nextInt();
        int[] palinList=new int[n];
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        {   

            palinList[i]=sc.nextInt();;
        }

        for(int j=0;j<n;j++)
        {   
            nextPalindromeGenerate(palinList[j]);

        }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You increment `n` to the next integer to test for being palindromic(!), save it in `origingal`, then trash `n` to see if it is a palindrome.  But you never reset `n` for the next iteration.

Comment: Thanks. That was really helpful. Also I didn't reset digit and rev every time the while loop began. Now the program is working.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was extremely trivial, merely resetting rev, digit and n to meaningful values. The working program is as follows :

```
import java.util.Scanner;




class nextPalindrome {

    public static void nextPalindromeGenerate(int n)
    {   
        int flag=1;         
        int digit;          //to store the mod value
        int rev=0;          //reverse of the number
        int original;       //dummy to store the original number

        if(n<10)
        {   System.out.println(n+1);    //If number is single digit, next smallest palindrome is n+1
            flag=0;


        }

        original=n;
        while(flag!=0)
        {   rev=0;digit=0;
            n=++original;

            while(n>0)      //loop for reversing the number
            {
                digit=n%10;
                rev=rev*10+digit;
                n=n/10;
            }

            if(rev==original)   //check if original equals the reverse(original)
            {
                System.out.println(original);
                flag=0;


            }

            else flag=1;
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {   

    @SuppressWarnings("resource")
    Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);




        int n=sc.nextInt();
        int[] palinList=new int[n];
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        {   

            palinList[i]=sc.nextInt();;
        }

        for(int j=0;j<n;j++)
        {   
            nextPalindromeGenerate(palinList[j]);

        }

}
}
```